# How to make web radiobuttons work the way I want

Tags: asp.net, radio-button

I’m working on an asp.net page that simplified looks like this: A group of  radiobuttons at the top, some asp dropdownlists in the middle and an asp button labled ”save” at the bottom. I want the page to work like this: When one radiobutton in the group has focus you should be able select one of the others by pressing the up and down arrow keys. At the same time different dropdownlists should be disabled or enabled depending on which radiobutton is selected. Then you select values from the enabled dropdownlists. Finally, by clicking ”save” values should be fetched both from the radiobuttons and the dropdownlists and passed via a procedure to a database. I’ve tried out html input radiobuttons, asp radiobutton and asp radiobuttonlist but have not managed to get the page to work the way I want it to. I’ll be very glad for help to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Write a project to display the flags of four different countries, depending on the setting of the radio buttons. In addition, display the name of the country in the large label under the flag picture box. The user also can choose to display or hide the form's title, the country name, and the name of the programmer. Use check boxes for the display/hide choices.

Comment: This is a very vague answer to a quite vague question.